# jquery validate before serialize

Tags: php, jquery, serialization, validation

I'm trying to verify that certain fields in my form are numeric and not text. 
Where would I start ?

If the fields are numeric, then serialize, if not then send an empty string. 
The reason I want to do this is because PHP sees the data for each variable as a string and not numeric.

this is my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "lib/calc.php",
      data: $("#calcQuery").serialize(),
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(response)
       {
       $("#calcBox").html(response);
       $("#calcBox").show(); 
       clearForm("#calcQuery");

       },
```

this is my form

```
<form id="calcQuery" class="ui-widget-shadow ui-corner-all" style="margin-top: 1em;">
  <fieldset class="ui-corner-all" >
  <table border="0" width="85%">
   <tr>
    <th><nobr><label for="curr_alloc">Current Space Allocation:</label></nobr></th> 
    <td align="right"><input type="text" size="5" name="curr_alloc" id="curr_alloc" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <table border="0" style="margin-left: .5em;">
     <tr>
     <td>
     <input type="radio" name="curr_unit" value="KB" /><label>KB</label>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>
     <input type="radio" name="curr_unit" value="MB" /><label>MB</label>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>
     <input type="radio" name="curr_unit" value="GB" checked /><label>GB</label>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>
     <input type="radio" name="curr_unit" value="TB" /><label>TB</label>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <th><nobr><label for="curr_percent">Current Usage Percentage:</label></nobr></th> 

    <td align="right"><input type="text" size="5" name="curr_percent" id="curr_percent"  /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th><nobr><label for="desired_percent">Desired Usage Percentage:</label></nobr></th> 

    <td align="right"><input type="text" size="5" name="desired_percent" id="desired_percent" /></td>

   </tr>
  </table>
  </fieldset> 

 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried PHP's function [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). It is quite easy to specify various rules on form submission.

Answer (score 1):

As Vincent Ramdhanie mentioned, the [validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin is a good option.

However, there are a few things I'd like to clarify:

> The reason I want to do this is because PHP sees the data for each variable as a string and not numeric.

The types of each field value will ALSO be string as far as the javascript/DOM on your page is concerned.  Therefore, even if the user enters a number, it's really just a string.   So in either case you will need to parse the string into a number (or let a library do it for you).

The second, important thing to remember is that you cannot rely on clientside validation as it is easily bypassed/broken.    You should really be validating the data on the server side, as well as on the client side.

**Update**

In response to your comment, I am not very familiar with PHP, but a quick googling shows me that this should work:

```
$foo = "3.123";
$bar = (float) $foo;
```

As I mentioned, I'm not a PHP programmer so there may be a better way to do it, but that should work.

Comment: Then how can I verify that I'm getting a number in PHP if it only sees it as a string ?

Comment: @SimplySeth you need to cast it / parse it.   I will update the response.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your probelm ,PHP have a good function named intval

[link] http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php